# Detect active database connections in ssms process

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm creating a windows forms app to automate the creation of C# Models and SQL stored procedures and I have a form for connecting to the database. I was wondering if there was a way for this form to automatically partially populate if I have SQL Management Studio open and connected to a server. Originally I was hoping to just be able to scan active processes and possibly scrape it from there, but the process doesn't seem to contain that info.

Ideally I'd like to populate the Server Name, and User Name.

[image: Database Connection Details Form]

Comment: You mean that it should somehow scan for SSMS process and get the username & password from whatever connection is open there? That would like a big security hole in SSMS if f that was possible

Comment: Just the server and user. The password should be impossible, I agree. But it's my local machine, not like I'm trying to access it from the internet.

Comment: The Title of the Process does become, "SQL Query.sql - SERVER\INSTANCE (USERNAME) - Microsoft SSQL Server Management Studio" if you have a new query open... but I don't really want to rely on the user having a query open and scanning the processes. If you don't have a query open, the Title of the Process is just "Solution 1".